# How to detect the paste action in UIWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uimenucontroller, uiresponder, uipasteboard

I know that UIMenuController will by default display pop action like Copy,Cut,Paste in UIWebview.I need to take the content from Pasteboard when paste action is happening.So I need to intercept the paste action of UIResponderStandardEditActions from Responder.

For me,the the paste action and others(copy/cut) too is not been called up.

```
- (void)paste:(id)sender
{
  NSLog(@"paste");
  [super paste:sender];
}
```

What i need to return in  ?

```
- (BOOL) canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I ran into the same problem when trying to intercept paste.

Comment: Nope,Still struck :(

Comment: Are you having the above code in a subclass of UIWebView or anywhere else? They should be in a subclass for them to get called.